# How to set radius for map clustering in android maps

Tags: android, android-maps-utils

I am a beginner in android development, and i am working on android maps Clustering, but i am not able to set clustering radius, please can anyone help me?

**Example:**
I want to cluster markers within some fixed range of distance, e.g. if i give radius 1km then all markers within one km range should be clustered.

I am referring this [library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) for clustering development

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: i need to same like your question